# In Visual Studio 2010 "Start debugging" option automatically always append Date time string to URL

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Let's say I want to open page foo.htm using F5 "Start debugging" option.  Is there some macro that can be added to VS that would open the page and always automatically append an arbitrary parameter to the query string:

```
              foo.htm?bar=Date().getTime().toString()
```

This would happen to any html page when opened in VS.

Alternatively, is there a setting that says to VS, "always read the html page from disk -- never used a cached version".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append below lines in your html page. It would ensure that you always read the html page from disk.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
</head>
```

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion. After clearing the cache, and then adding those meta instructions, VS does launch a fresh version of the page every time in IE.